# For geospatial indexing, what are the differences in features between Solr and MongoDB?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, solr, geolocation, geospatial

I'm currently using MySQL and Solr, but considering making some changes. Should I keep on using Solr for location-based search, or move the entire thing over to MongoDB?

Answer (score 2):

I did some experiments with both MongoDB & Solr. Don't have many data points to share, but from what I remember Solr had a much better performance than mongoDB when combining queries including both location and text.

Overall, since MongoDB does not have full-text search capability, and you are already using Solr, I would recommed to continue using it for search.

Comment: How possible is it within MongoDB to do text search on a single field? Would that be pretty inefficient compared to Solr?

Comment: You can do very basic stuff, more details are available here:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Full+Text+Search+in+Mongo
Since you are already using Solr, you'll loose a ton of features

Answer (score 0):

You can compute a geohash on your own. I've wrote a php library to lookup point of sales based on lat-lng pairs and spatial index. I also used it for a hierarchical cluster. It makes you indepedent from the database vendor and you have much more choice of the spatial index. You can grab my library at phpclasses.org (hilbert-curve).

Comment: How is your library in terms of performance? Now that I know I can use Solr for geospatial indexing, I'm not really sure what I need MongoDB for anymore. It's kind of a shame that there's not really any kind of decent fulltext search.

Comment: @ScottHildebrand: My library is very fast. It's uses a table-based approach instead of a recursion or a L-System. I've copy the method from Nick's spatial index quadtree hilbert curve blog and the book Hacker's delight.